# How to plot a changing linear equation (multiple stitched together) on one graph

Tags: python

For this assignment I have I need to show several linear equations on one graph, but when one part of the x-axis is reached, it has to change which linear equation is portrayed. We aren't allowed to use anything outside of pylab and basic conditionals, arrays, loops etc.

Several things have been tried, simply plotting each line on the graph, the issue here is that the lines continue when they should not. I cannot seem to put a limit on each individual line as well. Additionally I've tried creating a loop for each part of the x-axis, and plotting the different lines for each one, to little success.

```
STemp = ((-22/90)*latitude)+24
Depth = arange(0,2000,10)
SSTemp = STemp*1+(0*Depth)
DTemp = 2*1+(0*Depth)
c = -((((2-STemp)/800)*200)-STemp)
TTemp = (((2-STemp)/800)*Depth)+c
xlabel("Depth (Meters)",fontsize="large")
ylabel("Temperature (\u00B0C)",fontsize="large")
title("Temperature of Water vs Depth",fontsize="large")
plot(Depth, TTemp, 'b-', linewidth = 2, label = 'Thermocline')
plot(Depth, DTemp, 'b-', linewidth = 2, label = 'Deep')
plot(Depth, SSTemp, 'b-', linewidth = 2, label = 'Surface')
grid(True)
show()


while Depth[0]:
    plot(Depth, SSTemp, 'b-', linewidth = 2, label = 'Surface')
while Depth[20]:
    plot(Depth, TTemp, 'b-', linewidth = 2, label = 'Thermocline')
while Depth[199]:
    plot(Depth, DTemp, 'b-', linewidth = 2, label = 'Deep')
show()
```

The first attempt yields a graph that has all the lines wanted, but that run for far too long (the angled line is meant to connect the two, while the others aren't meant to continue before the intersection).
The second one doesn't even show up anymore. I have tried so many things with that one that it's lost most of it's original code.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is a short script that addresses your stumbling block

1. Import `pylab`, get the points on the *x*-axis (I prefer `linspace` that keeps both ending points, you've used `arange` but basically it's the same)

   ```
   from pylab import *
   x = linspace(0,10,101)
   ```
2. To define the linear functions use `where`, whose arguments, for this application, are a condition and two expressions, the value of `y?` is the first expression *where* the condition is true, the second one *where* the condition is false.
   Another point is the use of `NaN` (*Not a Number*), that is the Python representation of the result of an undefined numerical expression (e.g., `0/0`), that we use because in the context of plotting leads to a missing point in the line.
   Lets's say that we want to have *y = 2 x + 5* for *x <=5* and *y = 15* for *x > 5*, in code, using `where` and `NaN`

   ```
   y1 = where(x<=5, 2*x+5, NaN)  
   y2 = where(x< 5, NaN, 15.)
   ```
3. Eventually we plot the two functions, add the legend and a grid and finally `show()` our plot:

   ```
   plot(x,y1,label='linear')
   plot(x,y2,label='constant')
   legend() ; grid() ; show()
   ```

[image]

Ooops, I forgot to mention that you can concatenate `where`s, e.g.

```
from pylab import * 
x = linspace(0,10,101) 
x1, x2 = 4, 6 
y1 = where(x<=x1, 2*x+2, NaN) 
y2 = where(x< x1, NaN, where(x<=x2, 10, NaN)) 
y3 = where(x< x2, NaN, 22-2*x) 
for y, label in ((y1,'$y=2x+2$'), (y2,'$y=10$'), (y3,'$y=22-2x$')): 
    plot(x, y, label=label) 
ylim((-0.2, 10.2)) ; legend() ; grid() ; show()
```

[image]